# How to use CharSequence

Tags: java, charsequence

Hey i'm having some trouble understanding CharSequence. 

I think this will be the perfect method to help with my hw but im having trouble understanding how to use it. 

How do i make the sequence < /p> comes up.

This is what i have so far:

```
String s = "</p>";
char c;

while(reads.hasNext()){
c = reads.next();
    s = "" + c;
    if (inputPath.contains(?)) {
    // how do i make it return true if it contains < /p>
    }
}
```

Comment: Do i first have to make a loop that takes all the Chars and adds them to a string? AND THEN do the charseq?

Comment: A title about CharSequence and a question about String. And one needs to read the comments to understand this fact. Unreadable code.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are talking about [java.lang.CharSequence](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/CharSequence.html), it is an interface, and is the parent for String, StringBuilder, and StringBuffer (and some other things).

It looks like you are more looking to see if the input you have so fat has, or contains a given string `(</p>`).  To do that you could make use of the Pattern class or the String.equals or String.indexOf method (or the StringBuilder version).

Answer (score 1):

You can test that one String contains another using `indexOf()`:

```
if (inputPath.indexOf("< /p>") != -1) {
    // inputPath contains "< /p>" somewhere in it
}
```